# Fragment being created twice

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-api-2

I am aware that there are some questions with this same topic, but none of them apply to my case. I am building an app that uses a googleMap, but my problem is that the fragment is being created twice, which is causing problems such as slowing the app down and overlapping each other. This is how the program works: The main activity has a container, which at first holds a login fragment. If the login succeeds, the main activity detaches the login fragment and adds the map fragment.

```
public class MapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private Event mEventSelected;
private Person mPersonSelected;
private Map<Marker, Event> mMapMarkers;
private List<Polyline> mLines;
private TextView mPersonFullName;
private TextView mEventDescription;
private LinearLayout mMapEvent;
private ImageView mEventIcon;
private String mEventId;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    mMapMarkers = new HashMap<>();
    mLines = new ArrayList<>();
    mEventSelected = null;
    mPersonSelected = null;

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
    v = drawDefaultLayout(v);
    if (mMap == null)
    {
        initializeMap();
    }

    return v;
}

private void initializeMap() {

    mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.google_map)).getMap();
    if (getArguments() != null && getArguments().containsKey(FamilyMapData.getInstance().EVENT))
    {
        mEventId = getArguments().getString(FamilyMapData.getInstance().EVENT);
        drawCenteredMap();
    }
    pinEvents();
    markerHandler();
}

private void drawCenteredMap() {
    mEventSelected = FamilyMapData.getEvents().get(mEventId);
    setCurrentEvent();
    CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(mEventSelected.getLatitude(), mEventSelected.getLongitude()));
    mMap.moveCamera(center);
    drawLines();
}

private void pinEvents() {
    mMap.clear();
    Map <String, Event> events = FamilyMapData.getEvents();

    for (Event event : events.values())
    {
        LatLng coordinates = new LatLng(event.getLatitude(), event.getLongitude());
        String description = event.getDescription();
        if (Filter.sFilterMap.containsKey(description) && Filter.sFilterMap.get(description)) {

            float color = getColor(description);
            mMapMarkers.put(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(coordinates).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(color))), event);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">


<fragment
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:tag="@string/google_map"
    android:id="@+id/google_map"
    android:layout_weight="5"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:id="@+id/map_event">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/icon_event_divisor">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingStart="5dp"
                android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/event_icon"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/person_full_name"
                    android:textSize="10dp"
                    android:id="@id/person_full_name"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="8dp"
                    android:text="@string/event_description"
                    android:layout_below="@id/person_full_name"
                    android:id="@+id/event_description"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Can you help me figure why it's happening, so I can fix it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's a SupportMap fragment and You put another MapFragment inside of it's layout. This can be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you want adding extra work on original map fragment your fragment must extend MapFragment and if you want its callbacks :

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
public class MapFrag extends MapFragment implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener,
    GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener,
    GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener,
    GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener{
```

and then remove inflate section in `onCreateView` then change class tag in xml layout to address this class:

```
fragment
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="0dp"
class="yourPackage.MapFrag"
android:tag="@string/google_map"
android:id="@+id/google_map"
android:layout_weight="5"/>
```

then use `getMap()` method in your fragment class to access map instance and go on